# Is Ruby Range comparison implemented incorrectly?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, range

As in [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D), two ranges that represent the same elements are considered different:

```
(1..2).to_a # => [1, 2] 
(1...3).to_a # => [1, 2] 
(1..2) == (1...3) # => false
```

Why are two ranges that represent the same elements are considered different? I don't think that's how it works in math though.

In PostgreSQL, it is implement correctly:

```
test=# select int4range(1,2, '[]') = int4range(1,3, '[)');
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: *I don't think that's how it works in math* -- That is the way it works in math. [x, y] and [x, y) are different in math. Don't easily judge Ruby to be incorrect. Especially when it works as it is documented, there should be some reason for that feature. Do you think that Ruby developers are stupid enough to have math concepts incorrectly unlike you? I don't think so. I think it is the other way around.

Comment: @sawa no, they are the same on _discrete_ elements.

Comment: So what? How are discrete elements relevant in comparing the ranges?

Comment: @sawa example by PG: `select int4range(1,2, '[]') = int4range(1,3, '[)')` (`true`) VS `select numrange(1,2, '[]') = numrange(1,3, '[)')` (`false`),

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These ranges aren't equal - consider the case when you call `include?` with a floating-point value:

```
(1 .. 2).include? 2.5
false

(1 ... 3).include? 2.5
true
```

They *happen* to return the same results if you compare them to integers, but that doesn't mean they're identical.

Comment: Well, yeah. That is true indeed. I was only thinking about _dsscrete_ values in which case 2 ranges do represent same elements. But if we can take into account any numbers (or not even numbers) then yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

They just look same when you look at the results of `to_a`. But actually both ranges are not the same, because they to not cover the same range.

```
(1..2).cover?(2.99)
# => false

(1...3).cover?(2.99)
# => true
```

Comment: Your first paragraph and the code are correct, but the second paragraph looks wrong/misleading. It reads like you are suggesting that `(1...3)` covers the end value `3`, which is not the case.